# Oracle - how to truncate a timestamp to milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The oracle function `current_timestamp` creates a timestamp with microsecond resolution, i.e. 6 decimal digits:

```
> select current_timestamp from dual;

2018-04-26 13:20:07.253909
```

How can I (using pure SQL or PL/SQL) convert this to a milliseconds resolution with only 3 decimal digits and store it in a timestamp field:

```
2018-04-26 13:20:07.253
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') FROM dual;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(3)) FROM dual;
```

**Output**

```
TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF3')
-----------------------------------------------------
2018-04-26 13:26:16.642
```

Comment: When I want to store this in a timestamp field, do I need to convert it to char and back to timestamp using `to_timestamp()`?

Comment: Check Now I Edited My answer For timestamp @BastianVoigt

Comment: Be aware that `CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(3))` will round the milliseconds if additional precision exists.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper conversion would be

```
SELECT
    CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(3))
FROM dual;
```

`TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')` returns a `STRING` but not a `TIMESTAMP`, i.e. for further processing like `INTERVAL` operations you would have to convert it back to `TIMESTAMP`.